# CSS calc not working with viewport height

Tags: css

I am trying to prevent the footer of my page from 'jumping up' when the main content hasn't yet loaded. I tried the following css:

```css
    #main-container {
        min-height : calc(100vh - 200px); /* 200px being the height of the footer */
        background:red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main-container"></div>
```

This doesn't work. Chrome gives a message 'Invalid property'. But just writing `min-height : 100vh` works. Why is this happening? And what's the solution?

Comment: are you also keeping the comment? if yes remove it because comments in CSS need to use `/* */`

Comment: I am using Sass which compiles to CSS, and Sass accepts comments like that. Plus I have put the comment only here, not in real app. Changed it.

Comment: @G-Cyr Not sure what you mean. I am not getting any syntax error from Sass.

Comment: its more simple that i first thought , SASS do not require the  semicolon **`;`** at the end of the rule , remove it, it should work https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGbLYYr It requires your page to be taller than 200px also !

Comment: I made a snippet and it's working fine

Comment: Update your SASS compiler???